# Howto download speed nodejs request

Tags: node.js, networking, request, monitoring

I'm writing a spider like script for backing up and old forum website,
just interested in hacking into nodejs networking component to see and log download speed.

Im using request request({url:href, jar: j}), I think it uses http code module.
I did not succeed in finding something similar to:
process.memoryUsage().heapUsed
only for network usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure bandwith usage of your script, you may access this information through the socket/s objects used by *request* itsefl.

When processing the received available data through the 'data' event, the request object stores information about the ongoing connection.

Under the *agent.sockets* Object you can find the network sockets one being used. The bytesRead and bytesDispatched attributes may be what you are looking for.

```
request( { method: 'GET', uri: 'http://www.google.com')
.on('data', function(data) {
  //this.agent.sockets
  //this.agent.sockets["www.google.com:80"]["0"].bytesRead
  //this.agent.sockets["www.google.com:80"]["0"]._bytesDispatched
})
```

Comment: is it closely matched to response.body.toString().length ?

Comment: No, since body only holds the payload information of the HTTP request. Additional data (HTTP headers, TCP headers, control fields, etc...) are not reflected in here, but they are sent as well.
If you want to have an accurate measure of the amount data transmitted, you must refer to the sockets information.
On the other hand, if you only want to know how much data from your site has been transferred, the size of the body may be enough.

Comment: I don't need an accurate measure, but thenx anyway it looks useful.